# Is there a more efficient way to handle filters in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a large scale react app I am working on. In one page, there is a list of documents displayed. I have filters that can be applied to these documents, but these filters are state variables. The problem is that I worry this is "laggy" and causes list update delay.

I have the list of objects from the database stored in a state as so:

```js
const [ documents, setDocuments ] = useState<Array<Document>>([]);
```

And the states for the filters stored as such:

```js
  const [ createdBy, setCreatedBy ] = useState<string>('Any');
  const [ search, setSearch ] = useState<string>('');
  const [ open, setOpen ] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
  const [ onlyCert, setOnlyCert ] = useState<number>(0);
  const [ modifiedFilter, setModifiedFilter ] = useState<number>(0);
  const [ farFromAverageFilter, setFarFromAverageFilter ] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [ draftFilter, setDraftFilter ] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [ dupeFilter, setDupeFilter ] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [ sourceFilter, setSourceFilter ] = useState<string>('Any');
  const [ ageFilter, setAgeFilter ] = useState<[number, number]>([0,0]);

  const [ filteredDocs, setFilteredDocs ] = useState([]);
```

In which the filtered documents are stored in filteredDocs using the following useEffect hook:

```js
   useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredDocs((documents
      ?.filter(e => (
        search === '' ? e : `${e.data.vehicle.v_stock_no}${e.data.vehicle.v_make}${e.data.vehicle.v_model}${e.data.vehicle.v_vin_no}${e.data.vehicle.company_name}`.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g , '')))
      && (createdBy === 'Any' ? e : e.metadata.created_by_user_id === createdBy)
      && (onlyCert % 3 === 0 ? e : onlyCert % 3 === 1 ? e.data.vehicle.v_is_certified : !e.data.vehicle.v_is_certified)
      && (modifiedFilter % 3 === 0 ? e : modifiedFilter % 3 === 1 ? e.metadata.created_at === e.metadata.updated_at : e.metadata.created_at !== e.metadata.updated_at)
      && (farFromAverageFilter ? e.risky.length > 0 : e)
      && (sourceFilter === 'Any' ? e : (e?.data?.vehicle?.v_source?.toUpperCase() || '') === sourceFilter.toUpperCase())
      && (dupeFilter ? (documents.filter(x => e.data.vehicle.v_stock_no === x.data.vehicle.v_stock_no).length > 1 && documents.filter(x => e.data.vehicle.v_stock_no === x.data.vehicle.v_stock_no).every(e => !e.rollback))
          ||
              (documents.filter(x => e.data.vehicle.v_vin_no === x.data.vehicle.v_vin_no).length > 1 && documents.filter(x => e.data.vehicle.v_vin_no === x.data.vehicle.v_vin_no).every(e => !e.rollback)) : e)
      && (draftFilter ? e.draft : e)
      && (Math.abs(e.data.vehicle.v_days) >= ageFilter[0] && Math.abs(e.data.vehicle.v_days) <= ageFilter[1])
      )))
   }, [
      documents,
      search,
      createdBy,
      onlyCert,
      modifiedFilter,
      farFromAverageFilter,
      sourceFilter,
      dupeFilter,
      draftFilter,
      ageFilter
   ])
```

I know this has to be a poor way to do this, but I haven't figured out any better way to do this without reloading the page to use url query params.

Does anyone have any better ideas? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as I have been agonizing over this.

Thanks in advance so much!

originally I was applying the above `filter` to the map that created the list visually. This means it was running the filter every render so I changed it to a useEffect. But there must be a *better* way to do this.

Edit: I apologize for not being fully explanatory. What I mean by making the code "better" is making it more performant/efficient. I hope this clarifies a little bit!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "better." Fewer lines of code/fewer state variables/more concise code? More performant/faster loading/less lag? In what way do you want to improve this code?

Comment: If you're looking for a readability improvement, you could consider changing all the state variables to a single object, which would allow you to more cleanly factor out the filtering logic from the rest of your state. If you're looking for performance improvements, you could consider caching (fully or partially) the filter results each time the filters are changed, which would allow you to save time on future filter changes.

Comment: Hey @nullromo, great suggestions, thanks! And sorry about that, by better I mean more performant. Do you have a suggestion as to getting started on caching values? I have never done this before and it is a new concept to me. 

Extra info: the list array that is being rendered here contains 400-800 objects on average

Comment: There are different ways to implement caching, and it can get very complex. I would suggest looking into it more or posting a new question. Also, if the filter computation time is what's slowing you down, then it will help. If the amount of memory used is what's slowing you down, then adding extra cached data will hurt. But the idea is you would start with an empty `Map<FilterOptions, ResultType>`, get some options, generate results, then save that into the map. Next time you get some new options, you can first check the map to see if the results for those options were already evaluated or not

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` + `setState` isn't a bad starting point, but you really ought to use [`useMemo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo#skipping-expensive-recalculations) instead - caching / memoizing the result of an expensive calculation like this is its standard use case.

Only if that doesn't perform fast enough should you start looking into caching individual filter steps.

I'd also strongly encourage you to pull the filter parameters into their own object and rewrite the nested ternaries as a separate "filter" function. It will make the code much easier to understand and make it easier to test pieces of filtering logic; the improved ease of understanding will make it easier to go back and tinker with performance if needed.

Putting it all together (since it looks like you're using TypeScript):

```
interface FilterParams {
  search?: string;
  createdBy?: number;
  // etc.
}

function filterDocument(doc: Document, {search, createdBy}: FilterParams) {
  if (search) {
    const { vehicle: v } = doc.data;
    if (`${v.v_stock_no}${v.v_make}${v.v_model}${v.v_vin_no}${v.company_name}`.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g , '')))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (createdBy != null && doc.metadata.created_by_user_id !== createdBy) {
    return false;
  }
  // etc.
  return true;
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [ documents, setDocuments ] = useState<Array<Document>>([]);
  const [ filter, setFilter ] = useState<FilterParams>({});
  const filteredDocuments = useMemo(
    () => documents.filter(i => filterDocument(i, filter))
    [documents, filter]
  );
```

useMemo, basically, acts as "if any of the preconditions - `[documents, filter]` - have changed, then recalculate by rerunning the function. Otherwise, reuse the previous value of the calculation."

Regarding specific performance concerns:

- Refreshing the page has to recalculate everything regardless - you're not getting around that without doing advanced techniques like service workers or browser storage. If you're worried about that, you're better off finding ways to update documents without requiring a full page refresh. (For example, if the list of documents comes from an HTTP API, you could use a library such as [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query) or a [similar tool](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/comparison) to offer easy refreshing of the documents.)
- Under this technique, changing the filter will require reprocessing the documents list. However, modern JS should be able to filter a few hundred items without too much performance penalty. If you've benchmarked it and it's a problem, then you can look into optimization techniques.

Comment: What an amazing response!! Thank you. My one question is, would this hurt performance with things like changing a filter, refreshing the page to refresh the list, etc? I've never used useMemo so I don't understand its benefits all too well.

Comment: This is amazing... I will start on memoization for this function! Thank you for the responses.

Comment: Just an update... I implemented useMemo, but it actually makes the list take slightly longer to render, so I think it must be something else. Maybe I'll look into virtualization?

Comment: @MaxIntegrations - Okay. If you haven't yet, you might want to take a look at a profiler in your browser's dev tools - e.g., Chrome's built-in profiler can tell you if the filtering logic itself is taking a lot of time, while the [React DevTools profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html) can tell you if rendering the individual list items is what's slowing you down.